# Gulp transpile typescript stops working when importing package

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, gulp

I'm working in an angular 2 typescript app which has gulp tasks `gulp build` which transpiles to js and bundles and minifies it and gulp task `gulp build:dev` which does the same thing but without the minifying and bundling.

If I comment out this line in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { ClipboardModule } from 'ngx-clipboard';
```

Then the gulp tasks both work. But if I uncomment the line, then no javascript is output from both of the gulp tasks.

There are no error messages. How is this possible? I can't think of what can be going on, that would cause that one line of code to stop a gulp task working. Has anyone had a similar issue?

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('build', function (callback) { 
    runSeq('clean', 'copy', 'scripts', 'styles', callback); 
});

gulp.task('clean', ['clean:app', 'clean:css', 'clean:images', 'clean:lib', 'clean:root', 'clean:rootconfig', 'clean:rootall']);

//copy files
gulp.task('copy', function(callback) {
    //runSeq('clean:lib', 'copy:libs', 'copy:images', 'copy:config', 'copy:html', 'copy:configjson', callback); 
    runSeq('clean:lib', 'copy:libs', 'copy:images', 'copy:config', 'copy:html', 'copy:configjson', 'copy:schema', callback);
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(callback) { 
    runSeq(['clean:js'], 'ts', 'bundle:js', 'minify:js', callback); 
});

gulp.task('styles', function(callback) {
  //runSeq('clean:css', ['compile:less', 'compile:css'], 'minify:css', 'del:css', callback);
  runSeq('clean:css', 'copy:css', ['compile:less'], 'minify:css', 'del:css', callback); 
});
```

Comment: It seems like you should browserify your files first. Something similar to this
http://www.davidkudera.com/2015/02/28/typescript-gulp-bower-browserify/

Comment: This question needs a [mcve]. There's a lot of information missing. How are the `ts`, `bundle:js` and `minify:js` tasks implemented? What is the compiler's configuration? What's `runSeq` (That's not part of stock Gulp.) What code is being compiled exactly (besides the import)? Conversely, the question currently contains pieces of information that most likely have no bearing on the problem, like the `styles` task. And there may be other parts of the gulpfile that have no bearing on the issue at hand. Again, a [mcve] is what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common.js modules are not supported by TypeScript. When building for web browserify gulp pipeline should be supplied.

Example configuration should look like this:

```
gulp.task("default", ["copy-html"], function () {
 return browserify({
    basedir: '.',
    debug: true,
    entries: ['src/main.ts'],
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {}
 })
 .plugin(tsify)
 .bundle()
 .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

Full example and additional info here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html

Comment: Or use `--module amd` or `--module system`